# Twig Comparison Operator not behaving as it should

Tags: php, symfony, twig

Am trying to add a certain class to an anchor element if a given condition is met using symfony's twig templating engine, The following piece of code is being used in an attempt to achieve this:

```
{% if colors is defined and colors is not empty %}
{% for keys, c in colors %}
<li>
   <a id="{{ keys }}" data-rel="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="{{ c.color|capitalize }}" class="picker-btn{{ (colorData[keys] is defined and colorData[keys]['code'] == c.hexcode) ? ' selected':'' }}" style="background: {{ c.hexcode }}" data-color-id="{{ c.id }}" data-color-text="{{ c.color }}" data-color-code="{{ c.hexcode }}"></a>
</li>
{% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

The above code adds the `selected` class rightfully, to just the first anchor element even when I expect to have 3 anchor elements assigned this class:

```
{% if colors is defined and colors is not empty %}
{% for keys, c in colors %}
<li>
   <a id="{{ keys }}" data-rel="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="{{ c.color|capitalize }}" class="picker-btn{{ (colorData[keys] is defined and colorData[keys]['code'] in colors | keys) ? ' selected':'' }}" style="background: {{ c.hexcode }}" data-color-id="{{ c.id }}" data-color-text="{{ c.color }}" data-color-code="{{ c.hexcode }}"></a>
</li>
{% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

The second code fragment adds the `selected` class to 3 anchor elements because however you wish to look at it, `colorData[keys]['code']`has keys that exist in the `colors` array even if the class isn't being added to the right anchor elements. My question is this; if the `comparison operator (==)` returns `true` for matched variable values why isn't the first code fragment working? and why is the second code fragment adding this class to the wrong anchor elements?

A snapshot of the `colorData` array is shown below:
[image]

That of the `colors` array is thus:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

About the **first example** you're comparing:

1. "#FFFFFF" == "#FFFFFF"
2. "#222222" == "#795548"
3. "#01579b" == "#3e2723"

and after this comparsion it finishes 3 times in condition `colorData[keys] is defined`. What you can do here is to add one more loop.

```
{% if colors is defined and colors is not empty %}
{% for keys, c in colors %}
<li>
   {% set isColorInColorData = false %}
   {% for exactColor in colorData %}
        {% if exactColor.code == c.hexcode %}
             {% set isColorInColorData = true %}
        {% endif %}                
   {% endfor %}

   <a id="{{ keys }}" data-rel="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="{{ c.color|capitalize }}" class="picker-btn{{ isColorInColorData ? ' selected':'' }}" style="background: {{ c.hexcode }}" data-color-id="{{ c.id }}" data-color-text="{{ c.color }}" data-color-code="{{ c.hexcode }}"></a>
</li>
{% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

Looking to the **second example** you're comparing a string with an integer.

1. "#FFFFFF" in [0,1,2]
2. "#222222" in [0,1,2]
3. "#01579b" in [0,1,2]

Note that "#FFFFFF" is "equal"(==) to 0 in php!!

So you have to really concentrate on what are you comparing. In twig there is no `===` operator.

Comment: This worked in under 3 seconds! To imagine i crossed into 2018 with 2017 headache is unbelievable. Thanks for saving me from the headache

Comment: Hehe you're welcome. This is the one of few things that people hates in php. Anyway happy New Year!

Answer (score 1):

With the first code, you're saying

```
colorData[keys] is defined and colorData[keys]['code'] == c.hexcode
```

As you loop over an array of 3 items, `keys` is going to be 0, 1, 2 (or maybe 1, 2, 3 given it's Twig).  So you're saying

```
colorData[0]['code'] == c.hexcode
```

i.e. comparing colorData[0] with colors[0], so does #FFFFFF == #FFFFFF, which it does.

Second iteration, you're then comparing colorData[1] with colors[1], so does #795548 == #222222, and so on.

Comment: The second iteration compares ``colorData[1]['code']`` to ``colors[1]`` which results to ``#795548 == #222222`` as you have rightly pointed out, the class am talking about shouldn't be applied in this case since the color codes do not match.

Comment: On a second look at the above code, the ``colorData`` array has fewer items than the ``color`` array so when the iteration reaches the end of the ``colorData`` array, the loop is terminated. How do i fix this to ensure it loops through the ``color`` array despite the length of the ``colorData`` array?